# Hive AvroSerde on cluster exception

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hiveql

I have AVRO file and I need to map that file to HIVE table. The best solution for that is to use AvroSerDe.
So I used next commands on cluster:

```
 - CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_db.new_table
    ROW FORMAT SERDE
    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
    STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
    OUTPUTFORMAT
    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
    TBLPROPERTIES (
    'avro.schema.url'='hdfs:///folder/mySchema.avsc');





- LOAD DATA inpath '/folder/myFile.avro' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE my_db.new_table;
```

And all these commands executed successfully, but when I try to get data using hive query language, I have the exception on Hadoop map task:

```
SELECT
user.name as u_name,
FROM my_db.new_table
LATERAL VIEW explode(users) user_table as user;
```

Exception:

```
2015-05-27 13:22:24,838 DEBUG [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerdeUtils: Failed to open file system for uri hdfs:///folder/mySchema.avsc assuming it is not a FileSystem url
java.io.IOException: Incomplete HDFS URI, no host: hdfs:///folder/mySchema.avsc
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2596)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2630)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2612)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerdeUtils.getSchemaFromFS(AvroSerdeUtils.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerdeUtils.determineSchemaOrThrowException(AvroSerdeUtils.java:110)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroGenericRecordReader.getSchema(AvroGenericRecordReader.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroGenericRecordReader.<init>(AvroGenericRecordReader.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat.getRecordReader(AvroContainerInputFormat.java:51)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveRecordReader.<init>(CombineHiveRecordReader.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(HadoopShimsSecure.java:298)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.<init>(HadoopShimsSecure.java:259)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileInputFormatShim.getRecordReader(HadoopShimsSecure.java:386)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat.getRecordReader(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:652)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:169)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:429)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

**Hive version: 0.14**

**What is the reason of such kind of exception?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in

```
TBLPROPERTIES (
    'avro.schema.url'='hdfs:///folder/mySchema.avsc');
```

The avro.schema.url needs to contain MASTER_NODE_NAME + port in the url.
So the correct version is :

```
TBLPROPERTIES (
'avro.schema.url'='hdfs://MASTER_NODE_NAME:port/folder/mySchema.avsc');
```